# How do I pass a variable to an event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using FileSystemWatcher
On the Changed Event, I want to pass an integer variable.

e.g.

```
int count = someValue;
 FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "C:\temp";
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Changed);
```

on the fileSystemWatcher_Changed, I want to take the count value and then do some work.
But how do I get that value.

if I make count a global variable, it wouldn't be valid because count changes with each file changed event and it is passed from user.

Comment: Show the connections between Count, Watcher and Owner (a Form?). Is this Desktop or Asp.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a lambda expression:

```
watcher.Changed += (sender, args) => HandleWatcherChanged(count);
```

It sounds like you may want to pass `count` by reference though, if the method wants to update the value.

Comment: What is HandleWatcherChanged?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker it's the name of the method replacing your `fileSystemWatcher_Changed(..)`. You could use `HandleWatcherChanged(count, sender, args)` if you need access to these original parameters

Comment: It's a lambda expression.  It's basically a way to declare a method inline.  You're declaring an anonymous method whose args you'll call `sender` and `args`.  The types of these (and the return type of the method) are inferred based on how you're using it.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you subclass `FileSystemWatcher` and pass your count into the constructor of the subclass?

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a global dictionary mapping each file (path) to its count:

```
readonly Dictionary<string, int> filesChangeCount= 
    new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then, in your event handler, just increment the appropriate count in the dictionary:

```
void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock (filesChangeCount)
    {
        int count;
        filesChangeCount.TryGetValue(e.FullPath, out count);
        filesChangeCount[e.FullPath] = count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how often `fileSystemWatcher_Changed` was called globally, you could use a static variable as well. If you want to know the number of calls in one specific instance of the class, drop the `static` keyword.

```
private static int _count;

private void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("fileSystemWatcher_Changed was called {0} times",
                      ++_count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that if you are using a global variable in your changed handler you should surround any use of your variable with a lock since your changed event will be called by more than one thread.

```
private static int _count;
private object lockerObject = new object();
private void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(lockerObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fileSystemWatcher_Changed was called {0} times",
                  ++_count);
    }
}
```